# How do I allow access to a service running on a Forefront TMG Server?

Tags: firewall, zabbix, microsoft-ftmg-2010, microsoft-ftmg, zabbix-agent

I'm setting up Zabbix for monitoring on our network.  So far everything is going well, the agent is installed on all the servers.  All the servers except the Forefront one are communicating with the Zabbix server.  I cannot connect to the the Forefront machine via Telnet on port 10050, which is what is needed for the Zabbix Agent to work.

In my Forefront manager, I've added a protocol called **Zabbix-Agent**, it has **TCP 10050, Inbound** and **UDP 10050, Receive Send**.

Then I created a new **Access Rule**, called **Zabbix**.  Under the **Protocols** tab, I've selected **Selected protocols** and added the **Zabbix-Agent** protocol that I added earlier.  On the **From** tab, I've added **Internal**. On the **To* tab, I added **Local Host**.

That is rule no. 1 in my config.  When I go to **Troubleshooting** and the **Traffic Simulator**, my simulation scenario is **Non-Web access** from the IP Address of my Zabbix server, to the IP Address of my Forefront server on port 10050, TCP.  The test denies the traffic as shown below:

> **Denied Traffic**
>      **Rule Name:** Default rule
>      **Rule Order:** 6
>
> **Additional information**
>     **From:** Internal
>     **To:** Local Host
>     **Network Rule Name:** None - Route implied (Local Host traffic)
>     **Network Relationship:** Route
>     **Protocol:** Unidentified IP Traffic
>     **Rule Application Filter:**

What strikes me here is that it sees the protocol as **Unidentified IP Traffic**, whilst I've explicitly defined the protocol.

What am I doing wrong that is preventing the access that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the protocol settings as **TCP 10050 Outbound**: for TMG, that's an ***OUTGOING*** connection, from the source (Internal network) to the destination (Local Host).

I know this can be misleading, but TMG (just like ISA Server) doesn't *ever* use "inbound" protocol definitions for access rules, only for publishing rules. In TMG/ISA terminology, "inbound" doesn't mean "to this server": Local Host is a destination network, just like any other one.

Answer (score 0):

no idea what "forefront" is... just a couple of generic things that could go wrong :

1. is zabbix server ip part of whatever "Internal" is ?
2. is "Local Host" the host ip, localhost (127.0.0.1) or both ?

assuming that maybe the testing tool is at fault here, have you tried starting up zabbix agent daemon and telnetting to its port from zabbix server ?